# How to calculate retweet of any URL, without login from Twitter API

Tags: twitter

I am new to twitter API. Is there any way that i can get number of retweet of any URL.
I want to calculate it without any login into twitter.

Comment: why is this community wiki? you shouldn't put all your questions under community w ...

Comment: Well at the very least you need an account with Twitter. They don't just let anyone crawl their search API, for performance reasons. We'd see the fail whale all the time instead of like, daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to calculate? How effective your marketing strategy is?

This is not possible via twitter.

Of course you can do: use the search API via link:yourlink or you could use bit.ly and their statistics to see who tweeted about destinct urls. Another solution could be http://jetwick.com which is open source now

Answer (score 4):

This will return a simple json with a count property of re-tweets for a specific URL
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=SOME_URL_HERE

Example:

API CALL:

http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://techcrunch.com/2011/07/05/kissmetrics-now-lets-sites-analyze-their-users-browsing-habits-%E2%80%94%C2%A0before-they-even-sign-up/

JSON RESPONSE:

{"count":235,"url":"http://techcrunch.com/2011/07/05/kissmetrics-now-lets-sites-analyze-their-users-browsing-habits-%E2%80%94%C2%A0before-they-even-sign-up/"}

Comment: This no longer works, the domain `urls.api.twitter.com` does not resolve.